# How to avoid boilerplate code when loading images with Picasso library

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, picasso

Let's say I have a layout with 4 ImageView's. Each ImageView must contain picture downloaded from remote url. Such task I can easily achieve with Picasso library like this:

```
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photo1Url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_view_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.image_view_error_placeholder)
            .centerCrop()
            .tag(context)
            .fit()
            .into(feedListViewPhoto1);


    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photo2Url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_view_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.image_view_error_placeholder)
            .centerCrop()
            .tag(context)
            .fit()
            .into(feedListViewPhoto2);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photo3Url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_view_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.image_view_error_placeholder)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .tag(context)
            .fit()
            .into(feedListViewPhoto3);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photo4Url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_view_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.image_view_error_placeholder)
            .centerCrop()
            .tag(context)
            .fit()
            .into(feedListViewPhoto4);
```

But maybe there is more compact solution to achieve such goal? eg.: to write only one time "Picasso with" and pass all required url's and ImageView object references? Maybe some kind of `for` cycle solution would help?

Comment: you can create a custom imageview with stylable attributes to provide some of the static values and set these when you create the ciew from xml

Answer (score 1):

I strong recommend you to create a ImageLoader "service" inside your app.

First of all, create an Interface with the methods you need to download images and set into `ImageView` or to get bitmaps or features related:

```
public interface ImageService {

    public void downloadAndSetImage(Context context, String url, ImageView image);

    //Other important methods to you
}
```

With this, you can make implementatios with Picasso or other download systems. This is useful for example to change or test other systems  without break your app.

After that create the implementation for the methods with all the boilerplate code.

```
public class PicassoImageImpl implements ImageService {

    @Override
    public void downloadAndSetImage(Context context, ImageDownloadInfo imageDownloadInfo) {
        //All picasso code
    }
}
```

Then in your application you only have to instanciate your ImageService (I strong recommend you to use DependencyInyection or at least a central Factory to get instances) and make simple calls to the method you need.